# How to get only Date from datetime column using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a column in the database as EffectiveDate

which is the type of DateTime.

I have a linq query to get EffectiveDate from the table. but when I get I am getting EffectiveDate with time.

But in my linq query i need only Date I dont want the time for EffectiveDate.

how to write the Linq query for that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using entity Framework ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call the `Date` property on any `DateTime` struct

```
EffectiveDate.Date;
```

or call

```
EffectiveDate.ToShortDateString();
```

or use the "d" format when calling `ToString()` *more DateTime formats [here](http://hunterconcepts.com/tools/developer/formats).*

```
EffectiveDate.ToString("d");
```

---

Writing a Linq query could look like this:

```
someCollection.Select(i => i.EffectiveDate.ToShortDateString());
```

and if `EffectiveDate` is nullable you can try:

```
someCollection
    .Where(i => i.EffectiveDate.HasValue)
    .Select(i => i.EffectiveDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

---

[DateTime.Date Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

[DateTime.ToShortDateString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

> A string that contains the short date string representation of the current DateTime object.

Comment: I am not able to call DateTime.Date. its throwing run time Error.

Comment: @user If you are using Entity framework then you are right the EDM.DateTime does not have a .Date property. Check out [EDM.DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387157.aspx) for what methods you can use.

Comment: @Chad it's tagged `linq-to-sql` but if that's not what the OP is using then you're correct