# get date from datetime in linq and show gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime, gridview

I need to get date from datetime in linq like this:

```
var items = db.Students.ToList().Select(u => new { bi = u.Birthday.Date });
```

but items in grid are displayed as follows:

[image]

I've seen other questions:

**Question1:** [Linq - Select Date from DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021606/linq-select-date-from-datetime)

but when I edit code Similarly,

```
                var items = (from xx in db.Students                                     
                                 select new
                                 {
                                    EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(xx.Birthday)
                                 }).ToList();
```

I got a error in code!!

**Question2:** [How to get only Date from datetime column using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747732/how-to-get-only-date-from-datetime-column-using-linq)

but accepted answer to this question convert date to string!

**Question3:** [Linq to Entity get a Date from DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185470/linq-to-entity-get-a-date-from-datetime)

Answers similar to question1.

aspx for show grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">            
</asp:GridView>
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: where is the DateTime coming from?  Is it a string or a DateTime object?

Comment: Looks like while fetching the date you are getting only the date part, but while displaying you are not formatting. Before displaying your grid try to format using .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: Change the grid column's format attribute to whatever you want. What grid are you using? Where is the ASP.NET code that generates the grid?

Comment: You should really start using the search option. There are a million questions how to format a date. This question is no different.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this grid is simple for simplicity. I add aspx.

Comment: The [real duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449788/date-format-without-time-in-asp-net-gridview) shows how toformat data while data binding

Comment: @alisoltani *which* control are you using? Different controls have different properties, although I suspect you should really check a tutorial on ASP.NET data binding. Check the link in the previous comment

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can't know the 'real' duplicate since OP doesn't tell how he binds the data. Does he even bind the data? The previous question used `string.Format` so I have chosen to stay with that and close as this duplicate. I would welcome any other duplicate target though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah, sorry. Just got the update question from OP indeed showing a regular ASPX gridview :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman duplicate problem??!!

Comment: @PatrickHofman this is not exactly duplicate i voted for reopen

Comment: It was at the time of writing. Feel free to reopen it and close as the duplicate proposed by Panagiotis @fubo

Answer (score 0):

As you have been told before in your other questions; when you display your grid at some point `DateTime.ToString()` is called, this results in a default behavior of displaying date and time. The `DateTime.Date` property simply returns the date part of the DateTime as a DateTime; in other words it returns the same thing but with the time set to exactly 12:00 AM.

To get the only the date as a string, you want to call `DateTime.ToShortDateString`, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx

In short this has nothing to do with Linq, the problem occurs when you try to display your DateTime object within your grid and as such needs to be solved by adjusting the formatting of the grid cells.

Comment: No need for that. Most grids have format attributes for their columns. Even if they don't formatting in the ASPX file or view file is the best place to format the value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I'll reword my statement as that was what I was intending to say, but obviously I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: The OP was calling `String.Format` right inside the LINQ statement in the previous question. It isn't possible to answer correctly this question in its current form

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think the OP is confused about the cause of the problem, and so I'm attempting to resolve that confusion. I'll admit that I'm answering the implied question rather than the literal question.